# Remix nested dynamic route calls loader of the right file howewer renders the parent page

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

[image]

When calling the route /events/23/sections/38-service-2 remix is calling the loader of the file /events.$eventId.services.$serviceName.tsx but it is rendering the default function in /events.$eventId.tsx having the same result as if I called /events/23.

Does anyone have a clear explanation about what is going on in here?

This is the code of the nested route **/events.$eventID.services.$serviceName.tsx**

```
/events.$eventID.services.$serviceName.tsx

import type { LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { json,  } from "@remix-run/node";
import {

  useLoaderData,
  
} from "@remix-run/react";
import invariant from "tiny-invariant";

import { requireUserId } from "~/session.server";
import { getTicketsByEventAndService } from "~/utils/events.server";

export const loader = async ({ params, request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  await requireUserId(request);
  invariant(params.eventId, "noteId not found");
  
  console.log("Loader Details Service Page")
  const data = await getTicketsByEventAndService(Number(params.eventId),params.serviceName);
  //console.log("Loader Details Service Page: ",data)
  if (!data) {
    console.log("Service Detail Page Not found")
    throw new Response("Not Found", { status: 404 });
  }

  return json(data);
};



export default function ServiceDetailsPage() {
  const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  console.log("Tickets: ", data);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className="text-2xl font-bold"> Details Ticket page</h3>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the code of the parent file **/events.$eventID.tsx**

```
import type {  LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import { json} from "@remix-run/node";
import {
  Link,
  useLoaderData,
} from "@remix-run/react";
import invariant from "tiny-invariant";

import { requireUserId } from "~/session.server";
import { getTicketsByEventId } from "~/utils/events.server";

export const loader = async ({ params, request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  await requireUserId(request);
  invariant(params.eventId, "noteId not found");
  console.log("EventsPage Loader Called")
  const data = await getTicketsByEventId(Number(params.eventId));
  if (!data) {
    throw new Response("Not Found", { status: 404 });
  }

  return json(data);
};



export default function EventsPage() {
  const { tickets, inventory } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  console.log("EventsPage Rendered")
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className="text-2xl font-bold"> Total sold tickets: {tickets.length}</h3>
      <Link to={`services`}> Services Page</Link>
      {Object.keys(inventory).map((key) => {
        const event = inventory[key];
        return <EventRow key={key} event={event} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}



const EventRow = ({ event }) => {
  const totalServices = Object.keys(event).filter((key) =>
    key.startsWith("service"),
  ).length;

  const services = [];
  for (let idx = 1; idx <= totalServices; idx++) {
    services.push(event[`service-${idx}`]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col pt-10 divide-y divide-dashed hover:divide-solid">
      <h3 className="text-xl"> {event.text} </h3>
      <div className="flex flex-row items-start">
        {services.map((service) => (
          <Link to={`services/${service.key}`} key={service.key} className="text-lg pl-5 pt-5 border-r-8 hover:bg-orange-300">
            <p> {service.text}</p>
            <p> Sold: {service.sold}</p>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Remix `v2` routing convention, route nesting is determined by matching the longest parent prefix.

```
events.$eventId.tsx
events.$eventId.services.$serviceName.tsx
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this route is nested under events.$eventId
```

When nesting routes, the parent layout should have an `<Outlet>` to render the child routes.

If you don't want to use the parent layout, add the `_` suffix to prevent nesting.

```
events.$eventId.tsx
events.$eventId_.services.$serviceName.tsx
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this route does not nest anymore
```